# CQRS: Does the update of a model property imply the update of all the views caching that property?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Imagine a service like Twitter, where the users have an anchor name and a full name. Following the CQRS pattern, you generate views for the tweets containing the tweet body and the full name of the poster.

How would you handle an update of the user full name? Are you suppose to launch a long process to update all the views? I am thinking in a scenario where the users have thousands of tweets.

Comment: Well, that's what Twitter does - [Timelines at Scale](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Twitter-Timeline-Scalability) / [The Architecture Twitter Uses To Deal With 150M Active Users, 300K QPS, A 22 MB/S Firehose, And Send Tweets In Under 5 Seconds](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html). And as I remember, their reads are separated from writes, which is pretty the same as CQRS.

Comment: Eureka. Basically they are doing what I was doing before discovering DDD and CQRS (I hate joins): _Since the timeline only contains tweet IDs they must “hydrate” those tweets, that is find the text of the tweets. Given an array of IDs they can do a multiget and get the tweets in parallel from T-bird._ I bet they do the same with the UserId.

Answer (score 0):

Go not to the elves for counsel, for they will answer both yes and maybe.

So "yes"; the data in the write model has changed, and therefore a bunch of views that are built from the stale data have been invalidated, and should be rebuilt.  So you can think of the change to the write model having an associated UsernameChanged event, and the subscribers to that event know to signal that the views should be rebuilt.

"maybe"; you might already have that long running process anyway.  You might not need to track which views have been invalidated if you are rebuilding them all on a fixed schedule anyway.

"maybe"; [Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2010/11/15/the-known-unknowns-of-soa/) writes about this sort of thing, and made the following observation

> A service is the technical authority for a specific business capability.
>
> Any piece of data or rule must be owned by only one service.

His idea is that user full name would be private to that service -- which would have responsibility for both updating it and *presenting it*.  The service would keep the actual data private to itself, publishing only an identifier -- sort of a surrogate key -- and a widget, which knows how to fetch and present a representation of the name.

So the view wouldn't be filled with copies of the user name data, but instead copies of the user name *widget*, along with the state needed to identify the instance of the data that's of interest.  So a change to the user name wouldn't change "the view" at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you use the FullName widget, wouldn't you query the DB/Cache once per "tweet"? It does not seem very efficient, does it?

Comment: No, the widget would query its local data store once per tweet.

Comment: Yes, one hit per tweet/view you present to the user.

Comment: *local* data store - the efficiency is fine.

Comment: Do you know any article o book about this specific topic? I cannot find anything beyond the simple cases of just one single update.

Comment: Are you asking about data store, or about Udi's widget suggestion?

Comment: Widget suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you handle an update of the user full name?

Is it something that would be needed for historical tweets? You could argue that you shouldn't update the historical view at all if at the time of making the tweet they had a different name. The timeline would then show their name at the time of tweeting. This of course would be a business decision.

If it is needed, your view could read the most recent NameChanged event (for example) and use that for every tweet regardless of what it was at the time.

The last I heard of how twitter stores its data (from a podcast I think) is they have essentially a view per user where all tweets are copied, so if I have 100 followers, they would all get a copy of my tweets in their timeline....Unless it's a user with a high follower count, then they do something different (i might be completely wrong about this!) - in this scenario, your problem becomes worse because every tweet goes to every follower's personal timeline.

I'm curious now as to what actually happens! :)

Comment: just tested changing my profile name on twitter and it did update in another user's timeline, even for historical tweets

Comment: Exactly tomliversidge, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer presented by @tomliversidge but my response may be tool long for a comment, so please do not accept this as the 'correct' answer :)

It *is* going to be a business decision as to what happens to historical data.

Let's take another example to illustrate.  When I place an order I ordered SKU-001 which happened to be a "red bucket".  However, while waiting for my order to complete someone decided that the "red bucket" is actually a "blue bucket".  Now it becomes more interesting.  If only the Id of SKU-001 is stored on the order it means that what I ordered has now changed.  It will result in quite a bit of confusion.  There are ways around that though.  One is storing historical data and finding the item based on the date the order was placed.  But *that* is terribly complex and inefficient.  This is why one sometimes stores a value object containing both an Id and some pertinent information such as the description.  In the order example one certainly would *not* go back and change the description on historical data.

In this particular Twitter case it seems as though the historical data is updated.  Now, I don't know twitter and I'm not on it so I'll look at it a bit differently.  Having a user full name is also interesting in that the question becomes "Why was the name changed"?  It happens quite often when a woman gets married.  It may be that the business decides old full names are to be kept as that represented the state of affairs at that point in time.

However, if the data is to be updated it also becomes a bit of a technical exercise.  There are options here.  One, as stated in another answer, is to simply look up the user name when finding tweets.  Another, also stated, is denormalizing the data into the tweet.  Someone, somewhere, knows how this works.  Even if we have to denormalize the tweets it may be a matter of a single update run against the read model.  This is all going to depend on the technical implementation.

Just my 2 cents :)